# What is the most efficient way to substring specific portions of a text to a list of objects

Tags: c#, vcf-vcard

I have the following vCard text, my purpose is to parse the text to a list of vCard objects

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Kleit;Ali;;;
FN:Ali Kleit
TEL;CELL:70101010
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Kleit;Saeed;;;
FN:Saeed Kleit
TEL;CELL:03494949
END:VCARD
```

the following is my code to do that

```cs
 List<string> cards = new List<string>();

 if (text != null)
 {
     while (text.Length != 0)
     {
         int idx_begin = text.IndexOf("BEGIN:VCARD");

         if (idx_begin == -1)
             break;

         string endToken = "END:VCARD";
         int idx_end = text.IndexOf(endToken);

         if (idx_end == -1)
             break;

         string card = text.Substring(idx_begin, idx_end + endToken.Length);

         text = text.Substring(idx_end + endToken.Length);
         cards.Add(card);
     }
 }
```

next, using `Thought.vCards.vCard` .NET Library parser to parse each found vCard text

```cs
List<Thought.vCards.vCard> vCards = new List<Thought.vCards.vCard>();

List<string> failedStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (string card in cards)
{
    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(card))
    {
        var vCard = new Thought.vCards.vCard(sr);

        if (vCard == null)
        {
            failedStrings.Add(card);
            continue;
        }

        vCards.Add(vCard);
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to accomplish that knowing that the text might be in an incorrect format?

Comment: Instead of creating a list of strings why not parse the string values as you pull them out?

Comment: @juharr i actually split my code for better readability to point out the main purpose which is (substring specific portions of a text to a list of objects)

Comment: You can move the code to parse one vCard into a method and call it from the code that reads from the file to maintain the split and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var vcards = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Util.CurrentQueryPath), "Contacts.vcf"));

var vcardRe = new Regex(@"BEGIN:VCARD\s+(.+?)\s+END:VCARD", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);


var res = vcardRe.Matches(vcards)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(x => x.Groups[0].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).Last())
;

List<Thought.vCards.vCard> vCards = new List<Thought.vCards.vCard>();

List<string> failedStrings = new List<string>();

foreach(string card in res)
{
    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(card))
    {
        var vCard = new Thought.vCards.vCard(sr);

        if (vCard == null)
        {
            failedStrings.Add(card);
            continue;
        }

        vCards.Add(vCard);
    }
}

vCards.Dump();
```

Comment: nice way, but I tried parsing a whole list of vCards using your code it resulted (50) while expected (52). the first vCard had a photo property with base64 string. on the other hand, the first result included the first 2 vCards , while the others are as expected. it might be something to do with the regex expression

Comment: @AliKleit could be. If you can add some problematic examples, I could refine my expression.

Comment: sure, this is a .vcf file that contains 6 records (where resulted 4 using regex) [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EAm6bdCZ4tZrKq8Xca2Hh-CZDvJ_awoG) , while this is a screen capture of the results [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UEtQ14jfvTPUVxOCsAp-GLdH9eKe3e8G)

Comment: @AliKleit Well, regex is not enough for the whole task, but with a less ambitious expression and the library you have used it works.